# When returning a primitive variable, it is somewhat awkward that the content-type is `application/json`

Tags: spring, http, spring-mvc

Here's a simple example:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringConverterApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringConverterApplication.class, args);
  }

}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/demo")
class DemoController {

  @GetMapping("/b1")
  public boolean bool() {
    return true;
  }

  @GetMapping("/b2")
  public Boolean boolW() {
    return Boolean.FALSE;
  }
}
```

[image]

When I make an HTTP request, the response header has a `content-type` of `application/json`. I find this somewhat incomprehensible. I thought I would get a response like `text/plain`.

When I return `String`, it is responded with `text/plain;charset=UTF-8`. I think things like primitive variables should be responded like this, but maybe not?

Sure, I could create a converter, but it would be nice if `spring-mvc` included it by default.

Comment: I'm not familiar with spring boot but boolean is a JSON primitive.  So it probably assumes you want a JSON response.  https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159.html#section-13   indicates all primitive type examples as valid JSON

Comment: Oh... That's the first time I've noticed this, the example had something called a small JSON text, not an object or array .